# Why my coredns can not resolve the private domain?

Tags: dns, etcd, coredns

I deployed coredns and etcd on a machine for testing 
(with etcd as the endpoint). The configuration of coredns is as follows: coredns.conf,

Then etcd is as follows:

./etcdctl ls /skydns/com/mytest
/skydns/com/mytest/a
/skydns/com/mytest/b

./etcdctl get /skydns/com/mytest/a
{"host":"1.1.1.1"}

./etcdctl get /skydns/com/mytest/b
{"host":"1.1.1.1"}

then restart coredns and dig with 'dig @127.0.0.1 -p 1053 a.mytest.com'  for test, output as follow:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xshxd.png)

and output log as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgI9k.png)

coredns.conf as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBBVF.png)

so,why not out 1.1.1.1 ?

Comment: coredns version 1.6.7
etcd version 3.3.8

and when use coredns with version 1.1.4, resolving ok

Comment: have resloved it by update version of etcd